# .htaccess: AddHandler for a single file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, addhandler

I know that the `AddHandler` directive allows you to associate a file extension with a a process.

Is it possible to associate a single file with a process?

For example, I would like to process `something.css` go run a PHP script to generate some CSS dynamically.

From what I have read so far, it might be possible using something like:

```
<Files something.css>
    # go off to PHP script
</Files>
```

… but I don’t know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here’s how I got it working:

```
#   .htaccess
    <Files something.css>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /styles/something.php [QSA,L]
    </Files>
```

This goes directly into the `/styles/` directory, since you can’t specify directories in the `Files` directive.